# Excel Array formula IF with multiple criterias

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2016

In my spreadsheet using array formula I am creating a unique list of values based on multiple conditions. Formula is below:

```
{=INDEX(INDIRECT($O$3&"!$L$2:$L$"&$O$16),SMALL(IF((INDIRECT($I$3,FALSE)=$O$7)*(INDIRECT($K$3,FALSE)=$O$9)*(INDIRECT($M$3,FALSE)=$O$11)*(INDIRECT($X$17,FALSE)=$O$15)*(INDIRECT($AF$17,FALSE)>$O$15),ROW(INDIRECT($O$3&"!$L$2:$L$"&$O$16))-2,""),ROW()-20))}
```

Question belongs to this part if IF function:

```
(INDIRECT($K$3,FALSE)=$O$9)
```

Cell $O$9 contains drop down which includes one of cell content variables as well as <>, <>*, <> * Text*,""

When I use direct text match: specific column contains list of fruits and "apple" is one of the values, once $O$9 contains word "apple" formula works and I get a unique list. Should $O$9 contain any of above mentioned combinations (<>, <>*, <> * Text*,"") it gives me an error.

**Question**: How to change "=$O$9" so that it will be able to use following content of the $O$9 equals to <>, <>*, <> * Text*,"", etc.

**Note**: I cannot adjust drop down in cell $O$9 but can modify array formula only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry - you want to use the Content in cell `O9` as part of your criteria? So if in cell `O9` is "<>", you want the formula to resolve to `(Indirect($K$3,FALSE)=<>)`?

Comment: I don't think you can store logical operators in cells.  You also can't use wildcards in a comparision expression like you are trying to do. I'm assuming thats what the * is.  You would have to add a search function inside I believe but then the <> (not equal) wouldn't work as expected.  To me it sounds like you would need a user defined function.

Comment: Hello Bruce.
You are right. I would like to use below logical operators as a content of cell O9: <> - nonblank; <>* - blank; <>*Text* - not containing specific text; "" blank.

I am using same drop down in same worksheet for other COUNTIFS formulas.

Comment: One more thing, I am ready to adjust drop down list in cell O9 as last option.

Comment: It looks as if you would need at least three special cases - blank, non-blank or not containing specified text (using FIND or SEARCH if you wanted a partial match) - it could be done, but a bit of a long formula.

Comment: Can you share your vision on the formula could be look like so I can catch it up. I have no understanding at all how it could be sorted out anyway.

Comment: I will try and post something. Just wondering, do you need <>* or could you just use"" for blank? Also does <>*text* actually have * in it or could it just be <>text ?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is by no means a complete answer but just to show my thinking:-

Suppose you have two column ranges which I have called AA and BB and you want to implement some of your tests based on $O$9. It would look something like this:-

```
=SUM((BB=1)*IF($O$9="<>",AA<>"",IF($O$9="<>*",AA="",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*",$O$9)),ISERROR(FIND(MID($O$9,4,LEN($O$9)-1),AA)),$O$9=AA))))
```

So what I am saying is that your (INDIRECT($K$3,FALSE)=$O$9) would have to become something like the contents of the brackets following SUM above.